# How do I include dlib as part of my project in CLion?

Tags: c++, c++11, dlib

The current C++ setup is:

- Clion IDE
- dlib

I'm running one of the C++ examples given by dlib

```
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/image_transforms.h>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
using namespace dlib;

//  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // make sure the user entered an argument to this program
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            cout << "error, you have to enter a BMP file as an argument to this program" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Here we declare an image object that can store rgb_pixels.  Note that in 
        // dlib there is no explicit image object, just a 2D array and
        // various pixel types.  
        array2d<rgb_pixel> img;

        // Now load the image file into our image.  If something is wrong then
        // load_image() will throw an exception.  Also, if you linked with libpng
        // and libjpeg then load_image() can load PNG and JPEG files in addition
        // to BMP files.
        load_image(img, argv[1]);


        // Now let's use some image functions.  First let's blur the image a little.
        array2d<unsigned char> blurred_img;
        gaussian_blur(img, blurred_img); 

        // Now find the horizontal and vertical gradient images.
        array2d<short> horz_gradient, vert_gradient;
        array2d<unsigned char> edge_image;
        sobel_edge_detector(blurred_img, horz_gradient, vert_gradient);

        // now we do the non-maximum edge suppression step so that our edges are nice and thin
        suppress_non_maximum_edges(horz_gradient, vert_gradient, edge_image); 

        // Now we would like to see what our images look like.  So let's use a 
        // window to display them on the screen.  (Note that you can zoom into 
        // the window by holding CTRL and scrolling the mouse wheel)
        image_window my_window(edge_image, "Normal Edge Image");

        // We can also easily display the edge_image as a heatmap or using the jet color
        // scheme like so.
        image_window win_hot(heatmap(edge_image));
        image_window win_jet(jet(edge_image));

        // also make a window to display the original image
        image_window my_window2(img, "Original Image");

        // Sometimes you want to get input from the user about which pixels are important
        // for some task.  You can do this easily by trapping user clicks as shown below.
        // This loop executes every time the user double clicks on some image pixel and it
        // will terminate once the user closes the window.
        point p;
        while (my_window.get_next_double_click(p))
        {
            cout << "User double clicked on pixel:         " << p << endl;
            cout << "edge pixel value at this location is: " << (int)edge_image[p.y()][p.x()] << endl;
        }

        // wait until the user closes the windows before we let the program 
        // terminate.
        win_hot.wait_until_closed();
        my_window2.wait_until_closed();


        // Finally, note that you can access the elements of an image using the normal [row][column]
        // operator like so:
        cout << horz_gradient[0][3] << endl;
        cout << "number of rows in image:    " << horz_gradient.nr() << endl;
        cout << "number of columns in image: " << horz_gradient.nc() << endl;
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "exception thrown: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

This is how my current CMakeList.txt file looks right now

```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Project-Hurst)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(Project-Hurst ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I tried using the example CMakeList.txt file but it was not working properly. So how do I add dlib into my project path, and properly set up the CMakeList file?

Comment: What happened when you used the cmake file that comes with the example?

Comment: When I use the example CMake file, I get an error saying "include can not find load file"

Comment: Did you type the cmake commands exactly as shown here? http://dlib.net/compile.html

Comment: I'm using the clion IDE so it does it for me.

Answer (score 7):

You need to build dlib in the following way:

1. cd dlib
2. mkdir build --> cd build
3. cmake ..
4. make
5. sudo make install
6. sudo ldconfig --> will update shared library cache

this will create .so and dlibConfig.cmake files that will be recognized by CLion IDE.

Comment: initially, where should I place the dlib folder? For example, if the dlib is inside the C Drive as C:\dlib, then can I use the command sequence as suggested by you.

Comment: you are using windows, above commands will work on linux. I think once u install dlib via pip or build with source the path will eventually be configured by the python version you are using. u can use cmake https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: thank you for this help. I found the solution for Windows and I have posted it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have compiled dlib on your computer.
Then, add two statements below in your CMakeLists.txt,it will work.

```
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${dlib_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are looking answer for Windows operating system. Then you can follow the following simple steps.

1. Install C++ 11 compiler (compiler that supports C++ 11 or later versions). I will suggest using [TDM-GCC-64 Compiler](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/)
2. After installation of compiler set the path variable **C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin** to your operating system.
3. Next download dlib folder and extract it in **C:\dlib**. Now follow these steps. Assume you are in **C:\** location in your command prompt.

- cd dlib
- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
- mingw32-make
- mingw32-make install

4. Next copy the **dlibConfig.cmake** and **dlib.cmake** files to the **cmake-build-debug** folder. This folder will be inside your CLion C++ Project.
5. Now check inside the **dlibConfig.cmake** file, and in case you find a line like **include(C:/Program Files (x86)/Project/include/dlib/cmake_utils/use_cpp_11.cmake)** then convert it to **include("C:/Program Files (x86)/Project/include/dlib/cmake_utils/use_cpp_11.cmake")**.
6. Add the following lines in your **CMakeList.txt** file.

- **include_directories(${dlib_LIBRARIES})**
- **include_directories(${dlib_LIBS})**
- **include_directories(${dlib_INCLUDE_DIRS})**
- **target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${dlib_LIBS})**

Now you can use the dlib library in your CLion.