# How to set up Dlib as static installed shared lib in windows Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, dlib

I am using Cmake to link dlib. I read all the introduction and tried all the solution of other user. I cannot include dlib. I am getting error that the dlib find_package DLIb  cannot be found.

### My Projectstructure

testDlib

--testdlip.cpp

--cmakelist.tx

I am using the following Cmake-File.

### My cmakelist.txt

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)`

`project(testDlib)`

`find_package(DLIB REQUIRED)`

`add_executable(testDlib testdlip.cpp)`

`include_directories(${DLIB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY})`

`target_link_libraries(testDlib ${DLIB_LIBRARIES} DLIB)`

Thats how the cmake file should look like. But it won´t work because it cannot find dlib.
However what should  `${DLIB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}` and `${DLIB_LIBRARIES}` be ?

I tried following. 
dlib ist compiled and installed as a static shared lib in `C:\Programm File(x86)\dlib`. Now the next step is to link this in cmakefile.txt.
I set `${DLIB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}` as Windows environment variables variable. `DLIB_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY` points to `C:\Programm File(x86)\dlib\include`.

`${DLIB_LIBRARIES}` is also environment variables and points to  `C:\Programm File(x86)\dlib\lib`.

The amount of information out there is very much. But I am researching this 48 hours.

I also tried the solution of this [TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516241/how-do-i-include-dlib-as-part-of-my-project-in-clion).
This instruction are for linux and i did the same for windows:

```
You need to build dlib in the following way:

cd dlib

mkdir build --> cd build

cmake ..

make

sudo make install

sudo ldconfig --> will update shared library cache

this will create .so and dlibConfig.cmake files that will be recognized by 
CLion IDE.`
```

But how can I link dlib in cmake-File? He writes "this will create .so and dlibConfig.cmake files that will be recognized by 
    CLion IDE.`" how??

My dlibConfig.cmake is located in `C:\Programm File(x86)\dlib\lib\cmake\...`
The best way is just to tell from that giving lib location just how to set the lib in cmake.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To help other user, i am posting now the solution. I got it fixed. Only this solution is recomended for windows.

1. Download the dlib library
2. Use 7-zip un unzip it.
3. Open this path in clion and build the parent dir.
4. Open example and build the example just to check if it works
5. create same dir as example (dlibtest) and edit the cmake file for dlibtest.
6. Build dlibtest.

Thanks
Way